# Error when running random query in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, runtime

I am trying to run a query to select a random word from a table in SQLite but when I attempt to run  the app I get this error?

Random word method

```
public String randWord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
    new String[] { "*" }, null);

        String word = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD));
        return word;         
}
```

I get this error message when trying to run the app

```
01-07 14:46:24.448: E/AndroidRuntime(21664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 14:46:24.448: E/AndroidRuntime(21664): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replacing

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
  new String[] { "*" }, null);
```

with

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
```

as you don't have any host variables

Comment: Replaced the code, but now I get this error

'code' 01-07 14:59:02.348: E/AndroidRuntime(22429): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_WORDS: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 'code'

Comment: i certainly don't know your table name, replace `TABLE_WORDS` with the true table name and it should be ok....

Comment: Thanks that worked, sorry for the multiple edits on the comment, I am new to this website

Comment: if i helped you, pls ACCEPT my answer so i can get a bit of credit. and good luck!